# Ordinal arithmetics: $\alpha \cdot \omega \le \beta \implies \alpha + \beta = \beta$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

The original question was:

Let $\alpha,\beta$ be oridnals such that $\alpha\cdot\omega\leq\beta$.

prove/disprove: $\alpha+\beta=\beta$

So I tried to disprove with $\alpha=\omega,\beta=\omega^{\omega+1}$

But I got the feeling I did something wrong and I should actually prove that.

So I'll add a proof I thought of thanks to the comments:

$\alpha+\beta=\alpha+\alpha\cdot\omega+\gamma=\alpha(1+\omega)+\gamma=\alpha\cdot\omega+\gamma=\beta$

Is that correct?

Comment: $\omega\cdot\omega^\omega=\omega^{1+\omega}=\omega^\omega\ne\omega^{\omega+1}=\omega^\omega\cdot\omega$

Comment: Hint: look for a proof, not a disproof. It may help to write $\beta=\alpha\cdot\omega+\gamma.$

Comment: Yes, that proof works. However, if you write it up, make sure to mention why such a $\gamma$ exists.

Comment: There is a theorem that there exists such a $\gamma$ isn't there?

Answer (score 0):

First, here is a lemma: $\alpha+\alpha\cdot\omega=\alpha\cdot\omega$ for all ordinals $\alpha$.

Proof: If $\alpha=0$, then $\alpha\cdot\omega=0$, and $\alpha+\alpha\cdot\omega=\alpha+0=0$. If $\alpha>0$, then $\alpha+\alpha\cdot\omega$ is defined as $\textrm{sup}\{\alpha+\delta\mid\delta<\alpha\cdot\omega\}$, and since $\alpha\cdot\omega$ is itself defined as $\textrm{sup}\{\alpha\cdot n\mid n<\omega\}$, the former is equal to $\textrm{sup}\{\alpha+\alpha\cdot n\mid n<\omega\}$. Each $\alpha+\alpha\cdot n$ is equal to $\alpha\cdot(1+n)$ since ordinal multiplication is left-distributive ([ProofWiki page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ordinal_Multiplication_is_Left_Distributive)). Then $\textrm{sup}\{\alpha+\alpha\cdot n\mid n<\omega\}$ is equal to $\textrm{sup}\{\alpha\cdot(1+n)\mid n<\omega\}$. This set $\{\alpha\cdot(1+n)\mid n<\omega\}$ is the same set as $\{\alpha\cdot m\mid 1\leq m<\omega\}$, and the latter has the same supremum as $\{\alpha\cdot(1+n)\mid n<\omega\}$ because adding a new minimum element to a set of ordinals doesn't change its supremum. But this supremum, $\textrm{sup}\{\alpha\cdot m\mid m<\omega\}$, is the definition of $\alpha\cdot\omega$! $\square$

---

The proof sketched in the comments splits into two cases, one for $\beta=0$ and one for $\beta>0$.

For $\beta=0$ the statement $\alpha+\beta=\beta$ is trivial. (For $\alpha\cdot\omega\leq\beta$ to hold in the first place when $\beta=0$, also $\alpha$ has to equal $0$.)

For $\beta>0$, since it's known that $\alpha\cdot\omega\leq\beta$, it is possible to extract an ordinal $\gamma$ such that $\alpha\cdot\omega+\gamma=\beta$, by the argument on the ProofWiki page "[Ordinal Subtraction when Possible is Unique](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ordinal_Subtraction_when_Possible_is_Unique)". Once we have $\gamma$, we will try to put $\alpha+\beta$ into a related form. $\alpha+\beta$ is equal to $\alpha+(\alpha\cdot\omega+\gamma)$, and by associativity of ordinal addition ([ProofWiki page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ordinal_Addition_is_Associative)) this equals $(\alpha+\alpha\cdot\omega)+\gamma$. By the earlier lemma, this is equal to $\alpha\cdot\omega+\gamma$, which you may recognize is equal to $\beta$. So $\alpha+\beta$ was equal to $\beta$.